# StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatSnackBar -> Overlay] in Angular/NativeScript Project - How to fix?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to migrate my Angular project to NativeScript. 
 Whenever I'm trying to run `tns run android --bundle` I get the following error:

```
    JS ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:  
       StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatSnackBar -> Overlay]:
    JS:   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatSnackBar -> Overlay]: 
    JS:     NullInjectorError: No provider for Overlay!
    JS: Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for Overlay!
```

My Structure is like this:

```
src
  |- app
      |- search
           |- search.component.ts  # MatSnackBar is in here
      |- material
           |- material.module.ts  # MatSnackBarModule import is here
      |- app.module.ts  # imports MaterialModule(^) and OverlayModule`
```

Looking online didn't yield and results for me.

```
app.module.ts: 


    import ...

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ...
        MaterialModule,
        OverlayModule,
        ...
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...
        SearchComponent,
        ...
      ],
      providers: [], 
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

```
material.module.ts:


    import ...  

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ...
        MatSnackBarModule,

      ],
      exports: [
        ...
        MatSnackBarModule,

      ],
      declarations: [],
    })
    export class MaterialModule { }
```

```
search.component.ts:


    import ...
    import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
    import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-search',
        templateUrl: './search.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
        providers: [MaterialModule, MatSnackBar]
    })
    export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
                constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

        openSnackBar() {
            this.snackBar.open('Sorry' , 'Close' , {
                duration: 3000
            });
        }

    }
```

Interestingly, it works properly with `ng serve` but not with the above-mentioned command.

edit:
Removing MatModuls from SearchComponent gives following error:

```
JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
    StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SearchComponent -> MatSnackBar]:  
JS: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SearchComponent -> MatSnackBar]: 
JS: NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBar! 
JS: Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBar!
```

Comment: You're not supposed to set `MaterialModule` or `MatSnackBar` as a provider in your search component.

Comment: Will give me a different error tho (check edit)

Comment: As @Edric mentioned you can't import anything that's specific to Angular web within {N}.

Comment: @mortom123 did my answer worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `providers` from `@Component`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-search',
    templateUrl: './search.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
```